# Did a competitive-like problem right but need help on improving its efficiency

Tags: c++, optimization, time

The problem is simple. I'm given N - the number of digits in a number and then N digits of a number. I need to do exactly one digit-switch and get the highest number possible. I did do the problem right (as in gives out the right number) but it will be hitting the 1 second time restriction afaik. How do I improve on the efficiency of my program so it would go under the 1 second time restriction with N <= 10^6. New on Stack overflow so tell me if I did something wrong 
 with asking the question so I can fix it. Thanks. Here's my solution:

**main:**

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int a[n+1];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin >> a[i];
int maxofarray1;
bool changeHappened=false;
bool thereAreTwoSame=false;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) //changing the two digits to make the highest number if possible
{
    maxofarray1=maxofarray(a,i+1,n);
    if(a[i]<maxofarray1)
    {
        int temp=a[a[n]];
        a[a[n]]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
        changeHappened = true;
        break;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<n;++i) //need to check if there are two of the same digit so I can change 
//those two making the number the same instead of making it lower
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;++j)
        if(a[i]==a[j])
        {
            thereAreTwoSame=true;
            break;
        }

if(!changeHappened) //if the change has not been yet made, either leaving the number as is 
//(changing two same numbers) or changing the last two to do as little "damage" to the number
{
    if(!thereAreTwoSame)
    {
        int temp=a[n-1];
        a[n-1]=a[n-2];
        a[n-2]=temp;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
return 0;
```

**maxofarray:**

```
int maxofarray(int a[], int i,int n) //finding the maximum of the array from i to n
{
    int max1=0;
    int maxind;
    for(int j=i;j<n;++j)
    {
        if(max1<a[j])
        {
            max1=a[j];
            maxind=j;
        }
    }
    a[n]=maxind; //can't return both the index and maximum (without complicating with structs) 
    //so I add it as the last element
    return max1;
}
```

Comment: Your code example would be better in the form of a [mcve] or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You want more speed, so, did you build your code with optimizations enabled? You should *always* benchmark optimized/release builds, not debug builds.

Comment: you need to improve on the algorithm. Yours is too brute force and you need to rethink your strategy. As a hint: Consider you know the last appearance of the digit `9` in the number. How does this help you to know which two digits to swap?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 ooh I think I've got a much better algorithm idea from your hint. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Consider using `int_fast32_t` instead of `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is complexity. I didn't fully understand your algorithm, but having nested loops is a red flag. Instead of trying to improve bits and pieces of your code you should rather rethink your overall strategy.

Lets start by assuming the digit `9` does appear in the number. Consider the number is

```
9...9 c ...9...
```

where  `9...9` are the leading digits that are all `9` (possibly there are none of them). We cannot make the number bigger by swapping one of those.

`c` is the first digits `!=9`, ie its the place where we can put a `9` to get a bigger number. `9` is the digit that will make the number maximum when put in this place.

Last, `...9...` denotes the last appearance of the digit `9` and digits sourrinding that. After that `9` no other `9` appears. While we increase the number by replacing `c`, the number will get smaller be replacing that `9`, hence we have to choose the very last one.

For the general case only a tiny step more is needed. Here is a rough sketch:

```
 std::array<size_t,10> first_non_appearance;
 std::array<size_t,10> last_appearance;

 size_t n;
 std::cin >> n;
 std::vector<int> number(n);
 for (size_t i=0;i <n;++i) {
     std::cin >> a[i];
     for (int d=0;d<10;++d) {
         // keep track of first and last appearance of each digit
     }
 }

 size_t first = 0;
 size_t second = 0;
 for (int d=0;d<10;++d) {
      // determine biggest digit that appeared and use that
 }
 std:swap( a[first],a[last] );
```

It is not complete, perhaps requires handling of special cases (eg number with only one digit), but I hope it helps.

PS: You are using a variable length array (`int a[n+1];`), this is not standard C++. In C++ you should rather use a `std::vector` when you know the size only at runtime (and a `std::array` when the size is known).

Comment: I think I solved the problem with much less complexity thanks to your hint from the comment. When the numbers were typed in I remembered the index of the last of every digit and then used that to see which two should swap places. I did it very similar to your example you gave here + 2 special cases when the swap doesn't take place and there are 2 of the same numbers and when there are not. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

VLA (variable length arrays) are not standard. So instead of using this nonstandard feature, you might want to use a STL data type.
Given N is rather big, you also avoid stack overflow, given that VLA are allocated on the stack. And STL containers with variable length allocate on the heap.

Then, as you pointed out yourself, it makes sense to remember the index of the last occurrence of each digit, avoiding to search over and over again for a swap candidate index.

Your implementation idea is basically, to replace the first digit from the left, which has a bigger replacement to the right of it.

This is how I did it:

```
static void BigSwap(std::string& digits)
{
    int64_t fromRight[10];
    size_t ndigitsFound = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        fromRight[i] = -1;
    size_t i = digits.size() - 1;
    while (ndigitsFound < 10 && i > 0)
    {
        if (-1 == fromRight[digits[i] - '0'])
        {
            fromRight[digits[i] - '0'] = static_cast<int64_t>(i);
            ndigitsFound++;
        }
        i--;
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < digits.size(); j++)
    {
        char d = digits[j] - '0';
        for (char k = 9; k > d; k--)
        {
            if (fromRight[k] != -1 && static_cast<size_t>(fromRight[k]) > j)
            {
                auto temp = digits[j];
                digits[j] = k + '0';
                digits[fromRight[k]] = temp;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```